# Eclipse 4.2.1 plugin execution outside ide bundle not resolved errors

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp, eclipse-pde

I am facing bundle not resolved errors which ultimately lead to **java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.xyz.application" could not be found in the registry.** after upgrading to Eclipse 4.2.1. I get these issues when I run my application outside Eclipse and the app wont launch, the splash screen appears and I see a message to check logs.. Weirdly though the jars that are missing are found in the plugins directory of my application, I have checked the dependencies tab in Eclipse and added once again the bundles that are logged as not resolved but no luck, I have checked my MANIFEST file, but I see things are right- is bundle-version mandatory in the manifest for every bundle I use? I see some bundles don't have that property set in them.

There is one more thing to note here, in my previous Eclipse 3.7.2 builds the application after launching creates many folders in the configuration folder, I see all those folders in 4.2.1 except for org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal, and I see that during my pde build for 4.2.1 I see that ant tries ***twice*** to unzip org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl1 and org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl2.. and my nestedJars directory has just nl1 and nl2 jars for these two bunldes but the org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl1.jar file has lot many files apart from nl*jar - I think nl1 and nl2 jars are supposed to be moved too from nestedJars folder, because I see that all the other bundle folders under nestedJars have no .jar in them and infact only nl1.jar and nl2.jar of org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl1 and org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl2 are remaining in nested jars. So is this someway corrupt that they are ant tries to unzip twice ? or that it can't move the jars out of nestedJars?

Ant trying twice to unzip org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl1 during my pde headless build:
**[mkdir] Created dir: C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\AppCE\nestedJars\org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl1_3.2.600.v201209282147
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Users\Administrator\chechand_Common_3PT_3\vobs\fnet_3pt\Eclipse\4.2.1\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl1_3.2.600.v201209282147.jar into C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\AppCE\nestedJars\org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl1_3.2.600.v201209282147
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Users\Administrator\chechand_Common_3PT_3\vobs\fnet_3pt\Eclipse\4.2.1\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.nl1_3.2.600.v201209282147.jar into**

```
Also, here is the detailed error stack I get when I actually run the standalone application 
outside Eclipse IDE: 
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.071
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.071
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.103.1.v20120906-120042.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.071
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.071
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.emf.ecore_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3_0.12.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.core.commands_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.9.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.inject_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.core.services_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.9.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.annotation_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.072
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.emf.common.util_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.073
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-05-11 05:37:42.073
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling_0.0.0.
```

Here is the content of my .product file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="%Product.name" uid="CE debug" id="com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce.product" application="com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce.application" version="%Product.version" useFeatures="true" includeLaunchers="true">

   <aboutInfo>
      <image path="/com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.ui/icons/app_about.gif"/>
      <text>
         %About.text
      </text>
   </aboutInfo>

   <configIni use="default">
      <linux>/com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce/config/config.ini</linux>
      <macosx>/com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce/config/config.ini</macosx>
      <solaris>/com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce/config/config.ini</solaris>
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts</vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages i16="/com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.ui/icons/app_16.gif" i32="/com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.ui/icons/app_32.gif"/>

   <splash
      startupProgressRect="6,42,445,15"
      startupMessageRect="9,21,445,20"
      startupForegroundColor="000000" />
   <launcher name="configmgr">
      <solaris/>
      <win useIco="true">
         <ico path="/com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.ui/icons/config_mgmnt_multires.ico"/>
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
   </plugins>

   <features>
      <feature id="com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce.feature" version="5.2.0.qualifier"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" version="2.8.1.v20120911-0500"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.nls1" version="2.8.1.v201209282147"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.nls2" version="2.8.1.v201209282147"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.common" version="2.8.0.v20120911-0500"/>
   </features>


</product>
```

I would appreciate any help from you guys....

Comment: Are you using a .product file for the build? If so what is in it?

Comment: Hi Greg, 

I do see that my pde-build target internally uses .product file and I have added its contents to the question as it was too long to be added here.

Comment: Hi Greg, can you please advise me if anything is wrong, I have attached the .product file to my question.

Comment: I can't tell much from the product file. Which PDE build system are you using (there are several) or is this using some IBM code? It looks as though it may be looking in the wrong place for the plugins.

Comment: I changed my product configuration to use plugins instead of features and now when I launch I get an error which is very different when I launch my app outside eclipse:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.ui.util.Util
 at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:52)
.....I am using the pde build system that comes with Eclipse 4.2.1 I basically call productBuild.xml from my build.xml ant target called pde-build like this:

Comment: <java classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true">
   <arg value="-application"/>
   <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner"/>
   <arg value="-buildfile"/>
   <arg value="${3pt.eclipse.pde.build.plugin.dir}/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml"/>
   <arg value="-Dtimestamp=${timestamp}"/>
   <arg value="-DbaseLocation=${eclipseLocation}"/>
   <arg value="-DbuildDirectory=${buildDirectory}"/>
   <arg value="-DforceContextQualifier=${env.PLUGINVSID}"/> 
   <arg value="-consoleLog"/>